# Fetching Lowest and Highest Time of the Day from Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have a array of object like this this

```
const timings = [{
        monday: { from: "12:00", to: "13:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "10:00", to: "17:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "09:00", to: "10:00" },
        thursday: { from: "05:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "02:00", to: "13:30" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "13:00", to: "14:20" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "12:00", to: "13:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:40" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "16:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        sunday: {from: "00:00", to: "23:59"}
    },
]
```

I want the output to contain the lowest and highest timing of the day from the array

eg output:

```
{
    monday: { from: "10:00", to: "17:00" },
    tuesday: { from: "09:00", to: "13:40" },
    thursday: { from: "05:00", to: "16:00" },
    friday: { from: "02:00", to: "13:30" },
    saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    sunday: {from: "00:00", to: "23:59"}
}
```

I came up with the really long solution, but its really long and not efficient.

my solution

```
mondayFrom = timings.map(d => (d.monday && d.monday.from))
mondayTo = timings.map(d => (d.monday && d.monday.to))
tuesdayFrom = timings.map(d => (d.tuesday && d.tuesday.to))
// .... rest of the days
```

this will generate array from which i can find the minimum and maximum, but I feel its a bad logic.

If there is a better way, Please let me know. 
**Thank you**

Comment: I'd use `reduce`

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: May I know what rule i broke here ?

Comment: well it depends this array of timings does ever change? how often? how the user says to change it? do you need to do sth else with timings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using reduce makes it fairly simple

```js
const timings = [{
        monday: { from: "12:00", to: "13:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "10:00", to: "17:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "09:00", to: "10:00" },
        thursday: { from: "05:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "02:00", to: "13:30" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "13:00", to: "14:20" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "12:00", to: "13:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:40" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "16:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        sunday: {from: "00:00", to: "23:59"}
    },
]

let result = timings.reduce((a, x) => {
    Object.entries(x).forEach(([dow, obj]) => {
        if(!a[dow]) {
            a[dow] = Object.assign({}, obj);
        } else {
            a[dow].from = a[dow].from < obj.from ? a[dow].from : obj.from;
            a[dow].to = a[dow].to > obj.to ? a[dow].to : obj.to;
        }
    });
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

note: `a[dow] = Object.assign({}, obj);` so the original object won't get mutated

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exemple using `.reduce`:

```js
const timings = [{
        monday: { from: "12:00", to: "13:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "10:00", to: "17:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "09:00", to: "10:00" },
        thursday: { from: "05:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "02:00", to: "13:30" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "13:00", to: "14:20" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
    },

    {
        monday: { from: "12:00", to: "13:00" },
        tuesday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:40" },
        thursday: { from: "11:00", to: "16:00" },
        friday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        saturday: { from: "11:00", to: "13:00" },
        sunday: {from: "00:00", to: "23:59"}
    },
];

const formatTimings = function(timings) {

  return timings.reduce(function(result, timing) {
    Object.keys(timing).forEach(function(key) {
      result[key] = {
        from: !result[key] 
          ? timing[key].from 
          : [result[key].from, timing[key].from].sort()[0],
        to: !result[key]
          ? timing[key].to
          : [result[key].to, timing[key].to].sort().reverse()[0]
      };
    })
    return result
  }, {})

}

console.log(formatTimings(timings));
```